# mongoose, how to correctly remove reference with middleware?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, model, ref

can someone help me with a mongoose operation? I'm currently building this voting system.
I have this `Poll` model as:

```
var Poll = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    options: [{text:String, count: {type: Number, default: 0}}],
    author: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Account',
    },
    disabled: {
        type:Boolean,
        default: false,
    },
    date: {type: Date, defalut: Date.now},
});
```

and I have this Log model as:

```
var Log = new Schema({
    ip: String,
    voter: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Account'
    },
    poll: {
        type: Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Poll'
    },
    date: {type: Date, defalut: Date.now},
 });
```

each time a user vote for something , log will create something like:

```
{ ip: '::1',
  voter: 5824e7c3b6e659459818004f,
  poll: 58264b48f767f2270452b5cb,
  _id: 58264b4cf767f2270452b5ce }
```

now should a user delete one of his poll, say `58264b48f767f2270452b5cb` , I would like to also remove all the log documents that has same poll id in it.

I read some other answer and came up a middleware with

```
Poll.pre('remove', function(next){
  var err = new Error('something went wrong');
  this.model('Log').remove({poll: this._id}, function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
  })

  next(err);
});
```

but it's not working at all.

what should I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the current state `Model.remove()` calls don't use hooks, why? Because a document could not be present in memory at time of the call, so would be necessary to query mongo first and then delete the doc to make sure a hook would work properly.

There's a [CR](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1241) for adding this behavior but is not implemented, yet.

So the current way to do this is to use something like:

```
myDoc.remove();
```

An example, this won't work:

```
var myAccount = new Account({
  name: "jim"
})
var myPoll = new Poll({
  question: "You like stuff?"
})
var myLog = new Log({
  voter: myAccount,
  poll: myPoll
})

myAccount.save()
.then(myPoll.save())
.then(myLog.save())
.then(Poll.remove({
  question: "You like stuff?"
}, function(err) {
  console.log(err)
}))
```

This will work instead:

```
myAccount.save()
.then(myPoll.save())
.then(myLog.save())
.then(myPoll.remove(function(err) {
  console.log(err)
}))
```